# Retrieve public keys that signed a key I have

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

I am trying to figure out how to do the following in one command.

I have an ISO image along with its signature file *.sig. I tried to verify it via GnuPG 2 but it reported a missing public key giving me its fingerprint. I have successfully retrieved a key using the following

```
gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-key <fingerprint>
```

but when I checked the key

```
gpg2 --edit-key <KEY ID>
```

followed by

```
gpg> check
```

I have got this message:

```
27 signatures not checked due to missing keys
```

How can I retrieve all these keys to check that the key I have got is trusted?

Comment: I found a workaround using shell: `gpg2 --list-sigs <KEY ID> | grep "ID not found" | cut -c 14-29 | xargs --interactive gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-key' but I am still interested in `gpg2` if it exists. You know relying on number of characters in output is not the best approach

Comment: It turns out I need to `cut` with `14-31` instead of `14-29`

Answer (score 4):

You're not missing keys for the ISO's signature, but keys which issued certifications on the key that signed the image.

GnuPG does not recursively download other keys, you will have to do this on your own (for example, by running a command line like the one you proposed in the comments). But be aware that the certificates provided by other keys do not already assert the key's valid, it is very easy to generate whole networks of keys that even mimic the real OpenPGP web of trust like performed in the [Evil 32](https://evil32.com/) attack. If you want to validate some key by checking certifications, always build a trust path that ends at your own key (or some other key you verified through another medium, for example by meeting the person).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel like I need to go and read the whole manual. This is quite confusing; I know I can trust a key myself. Also, I still don't know if trust and validation is the same. I know I can sign a key. I read keys can be valid if certain conditions match, e.g. a key can be signed by one of the keys I fully trust. I don't understand what "issue certifications" mean! Is it the same as signing keys? Thanks